# HighCharts - Show dataLabel for last value in stockChart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to **show the last value of the stock on the chart**.

I've tried adding dataLabel but it doesn't work.

```
var data = [
  [1589973960000,506.5065,0.0],
  [1589974020000,506.3055,0.0],
  [1589974080000,506.1055,0.0],
  [1589974140000,506.1055,0.0],
  [1589974200000,506.005,0.0],
  [1589974260000,506.205,0.0],
  [1589974320000,null,null],
  [1589974380000,null,null]
];

// Calculate last non-empty index
var lastIndex = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i][1] == null) {
    lastIndex = i-1;
    break;
  }
}

data[lastIndex] = {
  x: data[lastIndex][0],
  y: data[lastIndex][1],
  z: data[lastIndex][2], 
  dataLabels: {enabled:true}
};
```

When I set it in chart options it works but that is displayed for all values. I want to display it just for the last value.

[Stock chart with last value visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Brdh.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dataLabel.formatter` callback to achieve the wanted effect.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a8t3zhs9/

```
  formatter() {
    let points = this.series.points;
    if (this.x === points[points.length - 1].x) {
      return this.y
    }
  }
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels.formatter

EDIT

---

@Nelie upgraded solution which detects null points in the chart: https://jsfiddle.net/1utz2x09/3/

Comment: Thank you! The solution doesn't work when I'm trying to get the last non-null value using the previous calculation when it is all wrapped in a getJSON() function. Could you please update?
It looks similar to this: https://jsfiddle.net/1utz2x09/3/

Comment: @Nelie, yeah sure, I updated my answer with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the other answer did not work as expected. I am using a dynamic chart where I am dynamically add points to the chart using Highchart's `series.addPoint(..)` API function. Using the above answer the dataLabel would disappear randomly.

So, I made a small utility function which I call every time after `series.addPoint(...)`. This function accepts Highchart Series object as parameter which can be obtained using `const series = chart?.series[0];`. This utility function could also work for static data when called after the chart is rendered.

```js
export function showLastPointDataLabel(series: Highcharts.Series) {
  series.points.forEach((point, index) => {
    if (index === (series.points.length - 1)) {
      // Only show data label for the last point
      point.update({
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true
        }
      });
    } else {
      // Hide data label for other points
      point.update({
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```